# Connect Ubuntu to other PC with direct (crossover) cable

Tags: networking, wireless, lan

Ubuntu 11.04 (PC-1) is connected to PC-2 (Windows XP) with LAN cable (crossover direct cable)
Internet access is through USB wireless modem accessing router in separate room

If I boot in Windows 7 (PC-1 has dual boot) I have no problem to connect to PC-2, at the same time being connected to Internet, even sharing my Internet connection with PC-2. I set static IP address and Subnet mask on both PCs and that's all for bare connection. Additionally I have set Remote Desktop Sharing and Internet connection sharing, which works as expected.

My problem:

1. I can't find a way to connect Ubuntu with PC-2 (Wired LAN connection)
2. When I was using Debian (month ago, as my first Linux experiance) I used Wicd and I could connect to PC-2, but I could not have Internet connection at the same time (either Wired or Wireless)

Can someone enlighten a bit this network issues, as man pages or help files aren't for bare mortals like me, but perhaps for network experts, as I did not understood a word in it

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/how-to-connect-share-your-internet-connection-wired-wireless)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to go into network manager and change your ip4 settings to shared to other computers

[image]

here is the other method using ip tables

this will set the ip of your ethernet card

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eth0
```

and this will configure the nat

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

if the connection you are using for internet is different from **wlan0** change that so if you are using mobile broadband it will most likely be **ppp0**

when you have done that you can save the settings by doing

```
sudo iptables-save > filename
```

and to reload the settings

```
iptables-restore < filename
```

the restore is needed because after a reboot iptables will forget what the settings entered above if you want it to load every time just put the restore line in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: PC-2 has static IP address: 192.168.1.2. I tried editing Routes (grayed button on your screenshot) and assigning IP 192.168.1.1 to PC-1 as that is set as Default gateway on PC-2. Unfortunately no results - I can't see PC-2 and I did log out - log in. I also tried this: [link] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/10741/how-to-set-up-dual-wired-and-wireless-connections) without success and your suggestion without success

Comment: ok forgot windows only has one set of rules for ip address i will edit my post to use iptables instead

Comment: Thanks Dave, but still no luck. I can't see PC-2 in Nautilus, nor I can connect with Remmina. I booted in Windows 7 to see if there are maybe some problems, but everything is fine there - I can connect to PC-2 filesystem and use RDC. Here are contents of the iptables file: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0XVQpC79

Comment: i do have another suggestion i changed the post slightly if you could set the iptable with eth0 instead of eth1 and also when you connect to internet is that through wifi

Comment: Now I can connect to PC-2 :) but Internet connection does not work. I now have both Wired (eth0) and Wireless (wlan0 I assume?) connected. If I want to use Internet I have to disconnect Wired connection and lose connection to PC-2. I enabled "Shared to other computers" in Wired (eth0), then in both Wired and Wireless profiles in NetworkManager, with same result. Here is iptables file now: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0czy4GJ6

Comment: i think it is prioritising eth0 over wlan0 for internet if you set your wired ip4 to manual on your ubuntu pc set the ip address to 192.168.1.1 you netmask to 255.255.255.0 and leave the gateway empty it won't default to eth0 you may want to add a second entry in wired with a gateway for when you connect the other way with internet on the windows pc