# How to connect two Ubuntu PCs to local network (without Windows PCs)?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

How can I connect two Ubuntu PCs to local network using Wi-Fi or direct ethernet cable connect for files transmission? I don't have Windows, so I don't want to install Samba.

Comment: a tutorial (in cmd line and without samba) is available here :
http://tuxtweaks.com/2008/10/how-to-set-up-a-home-network-with-ubuntu-part-1/

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/58161/connect-ubuntu-to-other-pc-with-direct-crossover-cable