# Connect Internet in ubuntu Laptop to linux mint Desktop - Has Crossover Cable

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, dns

I need to share the wifi internet of my ubuntu laptop to my linux mint desktop , I have a cross over cable. ( Connecting desktop to router is not an option)

I am able to ping my laptop from my desktop but unable to connect to internet.

I have first used network network manager settings in laptop to  and change your IPv4 settings to shared to other computers

`ifconfig` in **laptop** says

`wlan0`

```
IP address          192.168.1.4
Broadcast           192.168.1.255
Mask                255.255.255.0
```

`eth0`

```
IP address          10.42.0.1
Broadcast           10.42.0.255
Mask                255.255.255.0
```

NOW to the desktop where i need the internet, we tried both Automatic (DHCP) and manual settings under Wired Connection. Though able to ping the laptop not able to get the internet, *`ping google.com` says unknown host*. *`ping 64.233.160.1` (IP address of goolge) says `100% packet loss` `destination unreachable`*

In manual I gave IP `10.42.0.16` , tried gateways `10.42.0.1` once, tried gateway `192.168.1.1` ( which was shown in `netstat -nr`) tried gateway `192.168.1.4` and still able to ping 10.42.0.1 but no Internet connection

How can i remedy this. DNS entries are in router so shouldn't be a problem.

[Comments got hard to read, edited to add `route`'s]

`route` on  Desktop:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref  Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0             UG - 0 - 0   - 0 - eth0
1.42.0.0        *               255.255.255.0 -     U -  1 - 0   - 0 - eth0
192.168.1.1     *               255.255.255.255 -   UH - 0 - 0   - 0 - eth
```

and `route` on Laptop:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0 -           UG - 0 - 0  - 0 - wlan0
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0 -     U -  1 - 0  - 0 - eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0 -     U -  9 - 0  - 0 - wlan0
```

Comment: "able to ping my laptop from my laptop" ... ? What's the router address / laptop's gateway? Doesn't work for the desktop?

Comment: @Xen2050 Sorry my bad, it's "able to ping my laptop from my desktop", Desktop doesn't have a WiFi module so I can't connect to the WiFi internet. netstat -nr gives 192.168.1.1 for my laptop.

Comment: I'm familiar with the ping error "no route to host", but "destination unreachable" not so much. How's `route` look on each?

Comment: I just did. About out of ideas though, default's there

Comment: @Xen2050 Is there a way around this. I have functionally tried most of the things. What should i tweak

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I only commented & didn't answer :) Maybe start over following a guide to share internet from one Ubuntu to another?

Comment: @Xen2050 I have tried multiple times.. Tried rebooting multiple times as well.. Still unable to get the internet shared.. Perplexing

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](http://askubuntu.com/q/171914/65926)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little searching and found some answers, not quite identical but should work, it's supposed to be "easy" using the Ubuntu GUI tools. It'll set up some IP tables / NAT magic (somehow), so we were close with using "`route - show / manipulate the IP routing table`" but just didn't know the "secret words"

On the **internet connected computer (server)**, go to the Network Manager (right-click on the network icon(s) in the toolbar and edit the wired connection (eth0), go to the IPv4 tab and in "Method", choose "Shared to other computers". Apply everything and close the network manager windows.

Answers are a little different for the **non-internet (client)** computer.

- Some say to just plug it in & it'll work. Or set it to "Automatic" (and maybe set the dns server to the "server" computer if required) [[Share wireless with wired](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port), [share Ubuntu to WinXP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58161/connect-ubuntu-to-other-pc-with-direct-crossover-cable)]
- [Another says](https://askubuntu.com/a/194526) to manually set it's IP to one in the same LAN network, as in if the "server" is 192.168.1.4, then set the "client" to 192.168.1.5 with the same **Netmask** (255.255.255.0).
  Then use the "server" ip as the **gateway** and **dns**.

---

There's also a manual, terminal way to do it too using `iptables`, but the fellow's instructions are very sparse and don't explain what it does at all, except "this will configure the nat" (probably copypasta'd from somewhere else). I don't think it'd be useful to paste it here without an explanation so I won't, but [here's the link if you're interested](https://askubuntu.com/a/58527) (or a masochist ;-)

Comment: Thank you, the issue is solved and I'm posting from my desktop. :) I used the server IP as the **gateway** and **dns**

Comment: No problem. Too many variables to guess successfully, even what should make sense often doesn't. FYI, I've been using an old old wifi router to share wireless internet with local wired computers for a long time now, running Tomato or dd-wrt or openwrt gives many options, and should use less power than even a laptop.