# Connect Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 14.04 using crossover cable

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, files, ethernet, transfer

I have a Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu14.04 LTS Computers. I want to connect them to each other using Crossover cable so that I could Transfer files from Ubuntu to windows and back. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect Ubuntu to other PC with direct (crossover) cable](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58161/connect-ubuntu-to-other-pc-with-direct-crossover-cable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect the computers using your crossover cable (may not be necessary most modern ethernet cards should auto negotiate the connection see this [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable))
2. Setup both computers IPv4 settings:

   - On the Ubuntu computer go to network connections and edit your current connection by doing the following:

     - Select the IPv4 tab
     - Select "manual" from the method drop down box.
     - Click the add button
     - Enter an address that makes sense like 192.168.1.2
     - Enter a netmask that makes sense like 255.255.255.0
     - Gateway can be left blank.
   - I don't have a Windows 8.1 computer but you should be able to select the network adapter and configure the IPv4 settings.

     - Use a different IPv4 address that makes sense like 192.168.1.3
     - Use the same netmask
3. Verify the connection works by using the ping on the ubuntu computer:  open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> at the same time.  At the prompt, type: `ping 192.168.1.3` or the address of the Windows computer.  If you get a response, then the connection is working.
4. To transfer files you have a few choices. Windows file sharing (Samba), FTP, or SCP.  I would start with Windows file sharing.  Assuming you have the directory on Windows already setup for sharing.

   - On the Ubuntu computer open the Files application (this should be a file drawer on the launcher)
   - Open the File toolbar at the top.
   - Click Connect to server
   - Enter the following: `smb://192.168.1.3` or the address of the windows computer
   - Enter your Windows user name and password.
   - A new window should open with all the available shares.

Take a look at this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide).

Comment: Yes.  You should be able to follow the steps above.

Comment: I have succeeded in step3, only my terminal, after a few seconds, begins to say-  From 192.168.1.39 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: I do not have samba, could you tell me what to do step by step? Thanks

Comment: 1.  Check your IP addresses.  If you followed the directions your ubuntu computer should have an IP address of 192.168.2.2 and your windows computer should have an adress

Comment: Sorry incomplete comment.  Your windows computer should have an address of 192.168.1.3.  So your ping command should be 192.168.1.3 NOT 192.168.1.39.  Also check your internet settings by typing ifconfig at the terminal you should see your "inet addr" is 192.168.2.1 and it is "UP"

Comment: It would also help if you clarified the question...do you need help establishing the network connect or do you need help figuring out which service to use to transfer the files.

Comment: As you said above, my ubuntu pc has an ip address of 192.168.1.2

Comment: And Windows has- 192.168.1.3

Comment: I need help with configuring the service for file transfer. and when i try the code smb://192.168.1.3, it gives an error

Comment: Are you able to ping from one computer to the other?  If so on the ubuntu machine follow the smb instructions.  Open the file application icon (looks like a file cabinet).  Go to the file menu item on the toolbar.  Select connect to server.  Then type smb://192.168.1.2