# How can I give internet priority to wifi instead of ethernet?

Tags: 13.04

I have an old acer laptop (Aspire 5315-2077.) I'm using it to mainly browse the internet with while I'm using my more powerful system for gaming. I connect to the internet via wifi on the ubuntu system. I also have a wired LAN that does not connect to the internet. If plug the Ethernet cable into the LAN port on the laptop the wifi suddenly drops connection to the internet. I unplug it and I get internet. I suspect that ubuntu assumes that the wired network is faster for internet and assigns a higher priority to it. In my case, however, I need to keep priority on wifi for internet. Windows 7 allows me to assign a value to what's called an "Interface metric" no each of my connections. How can I do the same with ubuntu 13.04's connections? I have been looking for a solution for awhile and have not found it. I have found it is possible but, the person just asked if it was possible in their question and all the answers were basically yes without further explanation as to how. I am quite a novice with linux distros so, I don't have much more info about my configuration. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 19):

For Ubuntu 15.10, the procedure is more precise *where your wired network does not advertise a default route*.

Again, follow `Network Connections` into your `Wired Connection` and `IPv4 Settings`. Click `Routes...` and tick `Use this connection only for resources on its network`.

Now can you can proceed with more than one interface but retain Internet connectivity via your choice of interface.

Comment: not forget to re-enable your network settings

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

- Open `Network Connections` by searching for from Dash or open from
  its indicator on the top panel.
- Select the wired tab;
- Select your network and press Edit
- Uncheck the option: Connect automatically.
- Now on your wireless tab select your network and be sure to keep on connect automatically.

Comment: I'd love to try this. I have another problem now. I found this: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/ifmetric/ I believe this will solve my problem completely. I am stuck, however, in that I totally forgot the admin password that I used when installing Ubuntu. So, I am not able to allow any new programs or even update Ubuntu. My solution is to reinstall the OS from scratch (which I started before I read your solution, btw) and use a more common of my passwords so as not to forget it. Thank you for your response and I will post an update of my progress just as soon as I can.

Comment: Ok, back up and running. Your solution did not solve my problem. By unchecking "Connect automatically" I essentially just disabled my connection to the network. I could just unplug the ethernet cord and do the same thing. I would like to be able to access both networks simultaneously as to share files on my home network while also browsing the internet. I am now going to try that app and see if I can set the priority for internet to wifi and not ethernet. I will post my progress in the main section of the thread.

Comment: Works perfectly....

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my initial problem is solved. I figured it out myself. So you don't have to go through the stressful process yourselves, here's how to do it:

1: Click on the networks icon in the upper right corner from the desktop.

2: Click on "Edit connections".

3: Click Wired connection and choose Edit...

4: Click the IPv4 Settings tab.

5: Click the drop down menu next to "Method:"

6: Choose "Link-Local Only" in this menu

7: Click "Save" in the bottom right corner of the Editing Wired connection dialog box.

You may use your LAN and your wifi simultaneously.

Comment: This solution does not allow you to use a DHCP service that your wired router may provide, thus you won't be able to join your LAN.

Comment: The answer given by [Mathieu Trudel-Lapierre](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10741/how-to-set-up-dual-wired-and-wireless-connections), though for U10.04 (2010), shows how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue via following steps:

1. Open Network Settings.
2. Open `Wired` Tab.
3. Click `Advanced Settings`.
4. Click `General` Tab.
5. Untick `Automatically connect to this network when it is available`.