# Plugging in ethernet (internal network, no inet) cuts of Wifi inet

Tags: networking, wireless, routing

Im still pretty new to linux, but Ubuntu is my favorite.
As the title says:

Plugging in ethernet (internal network, no inet) cuts of Wifi inet.

I am using AnyDesk to connect to a ubuntu 20 box. All works untill i connect an ethernet with access to local network resources. This network does not have internet.

What happens is that my AnyDesk session gets disconnected. From what i see on the machine itself, its not to do with Anydesk and more to do with Ubuntu prefering the ethernet connection for all network traffic?

How can it be configured to "stay on the internet" with WiFi, and just accept the ethernet alongside?
I have experimentet some with Network/ Wifi under settings without luck.

Cheers, have a good sunday!

Comment: This may help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/424477

Comment: @turbulence - Hello! Yes this worked perfectly! I cannot mark a comment as an answer though, would you be inclined to "Answer" this case so i can award you?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I give internet priority to wifi instead of ethernet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424474/how-can-i-give-internet-priority-to-wifi-instead-of-ethernet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Maythux's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/424477) on [How can I give internet priority to wifi instead of ethernet?](https://askubuntu.com/q/424474)

> - Open **Network Connections** from its indicator on the top panel or open by searching it on the Dash;
> - Select the wired tab;
> - Select your network and press Edit;
> - Uncheck the option: Connect automatically;
> - Now on your wireless tab select your network and be sure to keep on connect automatically.

After this it should "stay on the internet" with WiFi.

Comment: Thanks again! No more bumps on this ride!