# Control which network interface is used by default

Tags: networking, network-manager

My mainboard hast two ethernet ports

So far i have only used one (eth1), which is connected to a router with a dhcp-server.

However, I want to use the other port (eth0) simultaneously to connect to another wlan router. The desktop is supposed to act as a hub, i.e. forward the dhcp services and all packages to the wlan, while still being a client in the network itsself.

- Is there any tutorial on this topic? (I couldn't find anything useful on google)

So far I am using a static ip setup for the wlan router (eth0).
As soon as I simply plug in the cable and connect with the network-manager, the internet connection is lost (even though the network manager shows, that both networks are connected). It appears that by default eth0 is then used for communication.

- using firefox or any piece of software, (how) can i control which network interface is used individually and by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up dual wired and wireless connections?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10741/how-to-set-up-dual-wired-and-wireless-connections)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to follow the advice from the linked Question: I checked the "Use this connection only for resources on its network" in the Routes Dialog for eth0. however, as soon as I turn the interface on, I cannot ping any ip anymore (neither of both routers).

Comment: To make sure, You are using different IP subnets for the two networks? Could add DHCP server or static IP setups used for both networks to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily disable the unwanted interface - ifconfig eth0 down. Otherwise, if you want an interface disabled by default you can add the same command to /etc/rc.local.  I suppose you could also set up xbindkeys to disable interfaces with keystroke as well.

Comment: Thank you, but i need both connections to be enabled simultaneously.