# Ubuntu 16.04 VPN with wifi - works only one

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

So I have VPN connection with this configuration:

[image]

But when I connecting to VPN network my wifi network disconnects? I've already tried `sudo service openvpn restart` but it doesn't work.

So my question is: How can I have access to internet via Wifi and VPN connection?

Comment: Check if this answer - how to set dual network on ubuntu : http://askubuntu.com/a/11084/544264 - solve your problem.

Comment: @Yaron, no after setting as it shown in asnwer, I could't connect to VPN

Comment: For my vpnc VPN connection I unchecked the option mentioned in the comment above and I was able to rdp with krdc. Just for others that might have this issue