# Can not connect both wireless and ethernet on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ethernet

I m working on clustering . When I connect two laptop through Ethernet connection or cable connection laptop can not  connect with wifi . I have set up ubuntu 14.04 on Accer laptop .. I need to connect both Ethernet and wifi at the same time on ubuntu .. Basically at present It can connect with one connection .

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered at [How to set up dual wired and wireless connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10741/how-to-set-up-dual-wired-and-wireless-connections)

Basically, you can only have one default gateway.  Ubuntu is going to choose wired e-net over wireless every time because wired is faster.  If the wired and wireless connections go to completely different networks (e.g. a secured e-net network at work and an insecure wireless network for guests) the above answer explains in detail how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank u so much .. I went to that link u recommended and it solved my problem. Now I can connect both Ethernet and wifi connection ..