# How can I use the network manager to connect to an internal and internet network?

Tags: network-manager, thinkpad, i3-wm

I want to connect to two networks: one via ethernet (an intranet without internet access) and WiFi for wireless access.

Both networks use a different subnet. I've setup a separate ethernet connection in the network manager so it is never set as the default route.

But whenever I activate the intranet connection, the wireless connection disconnects.

If it matters I'm using `nmtui` for configuration (using i3wm) and on a Thinkpad with the external ethernet adapter.

Instructions here did not help: [How to set up dual wired and wireless connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10741/how-to-set-up-dual-wired-and-wireless-connections)

Have just logged in using default Ubuntu Desktop (not i3wm) and was able to activate both connections. Is there a different in using `nmtui` and the GUI on the desktop toolbar?

Using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Having coexisting ethernet/wireless connections should work quite fine, I have a similiar setup myself. Reading your question, it seems that you set up those connections manually (?), so make sure that you configured them for the correct (seperate) interfaces.

Comment: @TimSchumacher The wireless connection is setup automatically. The wired one is one I created and works - but when I connect to one, the other is disconnected (and is removed from then list of available connections).