# Use both wifi and ethernet with internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, netplan, ubuntu-core

I'm looking for help to configure network on ubuntu core, I changed the netplan config and I manage to connect to both wifi and ethernet at the same time but there's an internet connection only on wifi. When I'm only on wifi internet works correctly but as soon as I plug the ethernet it stops and I can't ping anything. Is there an option to  "try" both network interfaces when pinging something or should I set some sort of priority (I don't even know if it's possible) ? Because in my case internet comes from wifi but it will not always be the case so forcing internet on wifi in some way is probably not the best solution.
I'm a beginner in both linux systems and networking so there's probably something obvious I didn't figure out.

Edit : As mentionned I'm using Ubuntu core so no GUI available. I'm changing netplan config via ssh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up dual wired and wireless connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10741/how-to-set-up-dual-wired-and-wireless-connections)

Comment: @24601 I can configure network interfaces only by ssh, I don't have that kind of GUI. i can set dhcp to true in the netplan config file but I don't know how to complete the second step where you check the "Use this connection only for resources on this network" option.